# apply several conditions in order to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has 3 columns ['a','b','c']. I want to apply a function on the whole dataframe based on several condition and tag them so I will get 4 new columns in my dataframe. I have the code below but it doesn't work and the error I get is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

and the code is:

```
if df['a'] is pd.NaT:
    df['is_open'] = df['c']
elif df['b']=='04' or df['b']=='14':
    df['is_wo'] = df['c']
elif (df['b']!='05') and (df['a'] is not pd.NaT):
    df['is_payment'] = df['c']
else:
    df['is_correction'] =  df['c']
```

do you know how I can apply these conditions? Note, that the order of conditions is important.

I have come up with this solution but is very slow on my large dataframe:

```
def get_open_debt_outcome(row):
    if row['a'] is pd.NaT:
        return row['c']
    else:
        return np.nan

def get_wo_outcome(row):
    if pd.isna(row['is_open'])  and (row['b']=='04' or row['b']=='14'):
        return row['c']
    else:
        return np.nan

def get_payment_outcome(row):
    if pd.isna(row['is_open']) and pd.isna(row['is_wo']) and (row['b']!='05') and (row['a'] is not pd.NaT):
        return row['c']
    else:
        return np.nan

def get_correction_outcome(row):
    if pd.isna(row['is_open']) and pd.isna(row['is_wo']) and pd.isna(row['is_payment']):
        return row['c']
    else:
        return np.nan


df['is_open'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_open_debt_outcome(x), axis=1)
df['is_wo'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_wo_outcome(x), axis=1)
df['is_payment'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_payment_outcome(x), axis=1)
df['is_correction'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_correction_outcome(x), axis=1)
```

**SOLUTION**:
based on the reply from @blacksite

```
mask = df['a'].isnull()
df['is_open'] = np.where(mask, df['c'], np.nan)

mask = (
    df['is_open'].isnull() &
    ((df['b'] == '04') | (df['b'] == '14'))
)
df['is_wo'] = np.where(mask, df['c'], np.nan)

mask = (
    df['is_open'].isnull() &
    df['is_wo'].isnull() &
    (df['b'] != '05') &
    df['a'].notnull()
)

df['is_payment'] = np.where(mask, df['c'], np.nan)

mask = (
        df['is_open'].isnull() &
        df['is_wo'].isnull() &
        df['is_payment'].isnull() 
    )

df['is_correction'] = np.where(mask, df['c'], np.nan)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the code doesn't work"? That is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can get the `'is_wo'` column. The rest is very similar:

```py
import numpy as np

# True-False indexing. Vectorized, so much faster than element-wise.
mask = (
    df['is_open'].isnull() &
    ((df['b'] == '04') | (df['b'] == '14'))
)
# numpy.where is basically an ifelse statement, taking a boolean vector as the first argument, and the desired values for true and false as the second and third arguments
df['is_wo'] = np.where(mask, df['c'], np.nan)
```

Oftentimes, `pandas.DataFrame.apply` can be very slow.